Hide the button if value of variable is missing
I am a novice in Javascript and I have a variable inside a for loop like below:
myTBody2 += `
<tr><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.first.href}')">First</button></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.self.href}')">Current</button></td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.next.href}')">Next</button> </td>
  <td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.last.href}')">Last </button></td>
</tr>`;

Now, say, if the value of ${data._links.next.href} is undefined or missing, how do I hide it?
Is there a javascript (vanilla JS) inline (one liner) function available to do that?
Any pseudo/pointers/solution will be greatly appreciated.
Update:
As asked by Jerico below, here is the data. I did not share it initially for brevity:
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "softwares" : [ {
      "createdBy" : "System",
      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",
      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "id" : 21,
      "softwarename" : "AWS16",
      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",
      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon16.com",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/21"
        },
        "appSoftware" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/21"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "createdBy" : "System",
      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",
      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "id" : 20,
      "softwarename" : "AWS15",
      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",
      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon15.com",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/20"
        },
        "appSoftware" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/20"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "createdBy" : "System",
      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",
      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "id" : 19,
      "softwarename" : "AWS14",
      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",
      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon14.com",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/19"
        },
        "appSoftware" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/19"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "createdBy" : "System",
      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",
      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "id" : 18,
      "softwarename" : "AWS13",
      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",
      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon13.com",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/18"
        },
        "appSoftware" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/18"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "createdBy" : "System",
      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",
      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",
      "id" : 17,
      "softwarename" : "AWS12",
      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",
      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon12.com",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/17"
        },
        "appSoftware" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/17"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "_links" : {
    "first" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=0&size=5"
    },
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=0&size=5"
    },
    "next" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=1&size=5"
    },
    "last" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=4&size=5"
    }
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 5,
    "totalElements" : 21,
    "totalPages" : 5,
    "number" : 0
  }
}

Solution that worked for me (for now at least) after trying pretty much everything here and similar other SO threads was to use just a try block like below:
let myTBody2 = "";
myTBody2 += `<tr>`;
if (`${data._links.first.href}`) {
    myTBody2 += `<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.first.href}')">First</button></td>`
}
if (`${data._links.self.href}`) {
    myTBody2 += `<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.self.href}')">Self</button></td>`
}
try {
        myTBody2 += `<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.prev.href}')">Previous</button></td>`
} catch (e) {
}
try {
        myTBody2 += `<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.next.href}')">Next</button></td>`
} catch (e) {
}
if (`${data._links.last.href}`) {
    myTBody2 += `<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.last.href}')">Last</button></td>`
}
document.getElementById('myTBody2').innerHTML = myTBody2;


use ternary or cretae a filtered array of all which are not missing and then map and join

There no language named java script there is java or javascript. there is no hypothetical "scripting" language based on the java language

I came up with a solution which allows you to add more data and ways to append or += to mTbody.
Working example with your data.


let toBeData = '{  "_embedded" : {    "softwares" : [ {      "createdBy" : "System",      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "id" : 21,      "softwarename" : "AWS16",      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon16.com",      "_links" : {        "self" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/21"        },        "appSoftware" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/21"        }      }    }, {      "createdBy" : "System",      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "id" : 20,      "softwarename" : "AWS15",      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon15.com",      "_links" : {        "self" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/20"        },        "appSoftware" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/20"        }      }    }, {      "createdBy" : "System",      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "id" : 19,      "softwarename" : "AWS14",      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon14.com",      "_links" : {        "self" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/19"        },        "appSoftware" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/19"        }      }    }, {      "createdBy" : "System",      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "id" : 18,      "softwarename" : "AWS13",      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon13.com",      "_links" : {        "self" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/18"        },        "appSoftware" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/18"        }      }    }, {      "createdBy" : "System",      "createdDate" : "2015-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "lastModifiedBy" : "System",      "lastModifiedDate" : "2023-12-31T05:00:00.000+00:00",      "id" : 17,      "softwarename" : "AWS12",      "softwareprovider" : "AMAZON",      "softwareprovidercontactemail" : "admin@amazon12.com",      "_links" : {        "self" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/17"        },        "appSoftware" : {          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/17"        }      }    } ]  },  "_links" : {    "first" : {      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=0&size=5"    },    "self" : {      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=0&size=5"    },    "next" : {      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=1&size=5"    },    "last" : {      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/softwares/search/softwarenameContaining?softwarename=&page=4&size=5"    }  },  "page" : {    "size" : 5,    "totalElements" : 21,    "totalPages" : 5,    "number" : 0  }}';

let data = JSON.parse(toBeData);

console.log([data]); //example return.


let mtb = document.querySelector("#mtb");
let arr = [data._links.first.href, data._links.self.href, data._links.next.href, data._links.last.href]
let indexName = ["First", "Current", "Next", "last"]
let myTBody2 = "";

myTBody2 += "<tr>";

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] === ""){
    //Do nothing.
  } else {
         myTBody2 += `<td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${arr[i]}')">${indexName[i]}</button></td>`
  }
}

myTBody2 += "</tr>";

mtb.innerHTML = myTBody2;
console.log("Result: " + myTBody2);
<div id="mtb"></div>



Also I don't check if the JSON value is null because the return in JS is "" instead of null.


let data = '{"thing": ""}'
let dataParsed = JSON.parse(data);

console.log([dataParsed.thing]); //example return.



EDIT
I changed to work with your JSON data. I also included an example return to show null over "".

myTBody2 = `
<tr>
    <td>
        ${ data?._links?.first?.href && 
             '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" onclick="myFetcher('${data._links.first.href}')">First</button>'}
    </td>

</tr>`;

you can check for the value inline using ${expression && 'expresssion is true'}
the ? is an optional chain, prevents errors if any value in the chain is undefined.
the last && in the expression is the return value
if there is an else condition use the tenary
`${expression ? 'if true' : 'if false'}` 

as others suggested but if there is not else condition tenary is not required.
